# Modify gates in Keras LSTM layer

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

How can I modify gates (forget, input etc.) in keras LSTM layer?How can I modify gates (forget, input etc.) in keras LSTM layer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to forget the cell state as the model train on data, you could use  this function to clear it `keras.backend.clear_session()`

Comment: No I mean can I for example add my own gate to keras LSTM layer or for example change the implementation of forget gate inside LSTM layer